# Monodroid doesn't support the previous version in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

Today i download the `visual studio 2015` .because i want to start android programming.

So i download `xamarin for visual studio` as you can see here :

[image]

So other packets are installed as you can see here :

[image]

So i create a `blank apps` and the code is like this :

```
namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
}
```

I install this file but i don't know what is that exactly i think it is simulator `mono-4.2.2.30-gtksharp-2.12.30-win32-0`.

But when i run this program

[image]

I get this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     @(Content) build action is not supported    App1    C:\Users\ehsan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
```

[image]

Some thing that i should add is there is no emulator in the list of visual :

[image]

Comment: MonoTouch tag is for iOS, so you should use this one.

Comment: Have you actually tried right clicking your project and click build?

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes i did .

Comment: Should i install gtk#?

Comment: GTK# is only needed for Xamarin.Studio to function